# explain the way to access inner class in java?

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
class Outer {    
    class Inner {       

    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Outer o = new Outer();
        Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();    

    }    
}
```

the way I create a reference for `Inner` class object is something like accessing `static` member in `Outer` class ? 
could you please explain the mechanism behind this ?

Comment: By the way, since it is not a `static` class, you need a live instance of `Outer` to create an instance of `Inner`. If `Inner` was `static`, then you could do `new Outer.Inner()`.

Comment: @okiharaherbst This is not a duplicate of the question that you linked (it might be a duplicate of some other question, I don't know for sure).

Comment: yes i am talking about the way of creating Inner class reference ? how its possible ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Look at the accepted answer there. I presume that this is the explanation sought by the OP.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I think it is a duplicate. What you explained in your answer is, in fact, what is explained in the accepted answer of that Q/A.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the way I create a reference for `Inner` class object is something like accessing `static` member in `Outer` class

Not at all - since you are using an instance of the `Outer` to access the constructor of the `Inner`, this is very much like accessing an *instance* member of the `Outer` class, not its `static` member. The name of the `Inner` class in the declaration is qualified with the name of its outer class `Outer` in order to avoid naming conflicts with top-level classes.

The reason for that is easy to understand: `Inner` is a non-static inner class, so it needs to reference an `Outer`. It does so implicitly, but the reference must be passed to the constructor behind the scene. Therefore, you call a constructor of `Inner` on an instance of `Outer`.

The syntax for making instances of `static` classes is similar to the syntax for making instances of regular classes, except the name of the nested class must be prefixed with the name of its outer class - i.e. following the `static` syntax:

```
class Outer {    
    static class Inner {       

    }    
}

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();    

    }    
}
```

Comment: still don't get the point i think :) , `Outer.Inner` is something like invoking a static member in Outer class ? is that ?

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha `Outer.Inner` is the full name of the type. The syntax looks similar because Java uses dot for scope resolution as well as for member access, but it is really a different operator: in the context of a type name, it means "The class `Inner` inside the class `Outer`".

Answer (score 5):

Not sure exactly what you are asking, but your code is valid.

You can only instantiate Inner if you have an instance of Outer, so you call only call Inner's constructor in the context of an instance of Outer, hence

```
Outer o = new Outer();
Inner i = o.new Inner();
```

works, but

```
Inner i = new Outer.Inner(); //bad
Inner i = Outer.new Inner(); //bad
```

are both trying to access Inner in a static way, and will not compile.

If you want create instances of Inner without first creating an instance of Outer, then Inner needs to be `static`

Answer (score 3):

You're actually accessing an inner class in a non-static way. A static inner class is actually different - the compiler makes a top-level class for it that is hidden from the programmer, which then works similarly to the way of instantiation that you have posted for the inner class.

You have to declare this way because since the inner class is non-static, it needs an instance of the outer class to make an instance of the inner class.

```
Outer o = new Outer();
```

is the required instance for the outer class.

```
Outer.Inner inner = o.new Inner();
```

is required for the instance of the inner class.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this looks weird is because you declared non-static inner class. That means that inner class will have access to instance variables in the enclosing class and would have to have a `this` reference to it.

Think of it this way: non-static inner class is a part of the enclosing class's instance like any other field. You need to specify a particular instance in order to create an object.
So just like you'd initialize a regular field like this (don't actually do that, it's bad):
`o.someField = new Object()`, you initialize inner class the way you did.